# MongoDB - Intermitted slowdowns involving sorting

Tags: mongodb, sorting

A couple buddies and I have been having a serious issue with MongoDB. Before I get in to this lets just get some stats out of the way.

Running on a Dedicated VPS with Softlayer

```
-Ubuntu 13.04 inside an ESX VM
-4 Virtual cores running at 2.0 GHz each
-48GB of RAM
-All on an SSD
-MongoDB Version 2.6.5 (and issue happening on the last 6 releases)
```

Were doing polygon geo queries using a 2dsphere index, as well a few other variables with ints and booleans added. There's about 7 keys total we'll query at a time, and then sort them afterwards depending what the user requests to sort by (Price, closest point to location, ect).

Now here's where things gets stupidly complicated. At random time in the days, specific locations will stop returning queries in a reasonable time, instead of the 300 to 2000 milliseconds average it returns in like 30 to 150 seconds, and this is ONLY for specific locations. Searching for New York City will return, but searching for London England will take ages.

The second we change what key were sorting by (we've even tried sorting by _id) everything goes back to normal. Then later on, that sort key will break for random locations, and by flipping it it repairs. Another method we found to fix is completely reindexing the key were sorting by (deleting and recreating), but then our search goes down for the time it takes to recreate the index.

This method works, sure, but changing the sorting method defeats the purpose, and reindexing is just more and more downtime for something that shouldn't be happening.

This issue could be a bunch of things, so let me just go through quickly the ones we've diagnosed and found not to be the issue.

```
-Does not relate to amount of users accessing database (Could be 0, could be 1000).
-Lock is averaged at 2.5% or below.
-Btree is normal between 0 and 200.
-Happens even when not writing to database (and haven't done so in hours)
-CPU usage is minimal
-RAM usage is only 60% average.
-Data in listings are valid.
-All keys within the indexes are the proper types. No string in int indexes, no datetimes in float indexs, ect.
-Has nothing to do with how many results are returned. Issue happens in locations where there is 10000 results, or just 5.
-No errors in logs, no errors in MMS, no errors anywhere... Just slow.
```

I'm out of ideas here, I simply can't figure out what it may be. Has anyone ever come across something like this? Or have any ideas on what it may be? Anything is appreciated. If I've forgotten to mention something or need to redo how I've explained it please just ask, no issues rewriting. Thanks again.

Comment: I have never heard this. Does this happen after some activity, you say the index data is fine but is there a correlation between what could be inputted and this problem? Maybe there is a piece of data that is causing hell? You say when not writing to DB but did you check performance right after you wrote to DB last? I am guessing this happens on both high and low utilization right?

Comment: Another good test is to get a db you know is good and to make no changes or other connections/queries etc etc to it and then see if that collapses

Comment: have same problem, someone pls solve

Comment: Can you show us the queries and an example doc? An explain for the queries, when slow but also possibly when fast, will be very helpful too. Have you tried querying with no location restriction and a sort when a particular value of the location field misbehaves?